# 802.1X needs 802.1AE more than 802.1, 802.3 does, true?

Tags: security, ieee-802.1ax

In some networks basics course the statement was made by lecturer 802.1AE was the extension  developed and implemented due to shortages of 802.1X. No references were made, at this point, to the fundamental 802.1, 802.3 suite. I wonder if 802.1X really needs 802.1AE more than 802.1/802.3 does.
In my own judgement, which can however be wrong, the need for 802.1AE might be at similar level both 802.1X and 802.2/802.3 sides.

Shouldn't fundamental suite 802.1/802.3 be interested in 802.1AE use in same extent as X-one is?

Comment: For the record, you can build a network using *both*. And 1ae can be used without network infrastructure support. (it starts to look like IPSec at that point.) But yes, 1ae is meant to encrypt traffic on-the-wire at the interface, but in the process it's also authenticating the node(s).

Answer (score 1):

IEEE 802.1AE aka MACsec may be seen as a successor to 802.1X (port access control). There is nothing in 802.1X that requires the later 802.1AE. In reverse, there are several aspects of 802.1X that are re-used in 802.1AE.

The IEEE 802.1 standards deal with data link layer technologies (OSI layer 2), you find more detail at https://1.ieee802.org/. IEEE 802.3 defines Ethernet for the physical and the data link layer (OSI layer 1 and Ethernet specifics for layer 2), see https://www.ieee802.org/3/. Former IEEE 802.2 was about the logical link control sublayer. It disbanded and dissolved into 802.1.

If you're starting with networks basic you might want to just take a quick note of 802.1X and 802.1AE for now, and concentrate on the more important basic details. If you want to dive in, you can get most IEEE 802 standards here after free registration: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I like to get understandable that one stress made in course. I am no network expert however some knowledge is present - achieved in tasks accomplished so far. Ethernet topic is first small chapter of quite big course.

Comment: Unfortunately no free resources nor need at present to dig more into topics of Ethernet. The need exists to clarify unclear points got in course introductory part.

Comment: I addition to answering your question I wanted to clear up the confusion that you seem to have about the different standard families.

Comment: You're right. As next I need to take look at ieee documents. Me was not aware these to be free. Thanks for hint.